# display a set password dialog after login

Tags: tapestry

When I create a user in my application he is getting a random password that he has to change after he logged in for the first time. Now my problem is to show that modal dialog where he is setting his new password. I can show the login dialog with a login button that opens the form. But for the set password dialog I don't want to use a button. The dialog should appear after the user is logged in for the first time (or when the password has been reset).

this is my login button that open the login modal form.

```
<a
    data-toggle="modal"
    href="#loginModal"
    id="buttongetstarted">
         ${message:login}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Open an modal after user logged in for the first time using this approach:

Firstly create a boolean field at server side for the users. Initially, u generate a random password for the user and set the flag field to true.

Then check at login handler when the user is logged in for the flag value

```
if flag is true
```

redirect the user to change password page or section
on successful change of password the set the flag to false;
    else
     Redirect the user where you wanted him to go.